# Making edits to remove historical references

Tags: discussion

I've had [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15342871) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15216862) rejected recently that attempted to remove historical "UPDATE" like messages. They were rejected on the grounds of not helping the readability of the question. The edits mostly try to remove historical preambles and appendices, which I *very personally* thought would help with the readability of the question. I (naively) figured this was similar to deleting obsolete comments, which initially helped with crafting the post, but are now distracting.

Is there an existing policy on edits like these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first edit you removed the attribution which is required, otherwise you're making it look like the writer has partially plagiarised his answer from the comments.

In the second edit you've removed the initial link, that's removing content rather than just cleaning up. You should have either left that part alone or rewritten it preserving the link.

Comment: Reviewers, if you see this: use the "Reject and edit" button! The meta edits shouldn't be kept and your action confuses editors!